# Creating database in Python using sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I got stuck when I was trying to create database in Python using sqlite3. The below is what I did. When I tried to run, it kept telling me the tables already exist. I couldn't figure out why. Thanks!

```
import sqlite3
variables = (data)
functions = (data)
var_func = (data)

conn = sqlite3.connect('python_database')
c = conn.cursor()
#create table
c.execute(''' CREATE table variable_table (
    id integer,
    name text,
    module text,
    type text,
    desc text) ''')

c.execute(''' CREATE table function_table (
    id integer,
    name text) ''')

c.execute(''' CREATE table var_func_table (
    variable_id integer,
    function_id integer,
    type text) ''')
#fill tables with data
for row in variables:
    c.execute ('insert into variable_table values (?,?,?,?,?)', row )
for row in functions:
    c.execute ('insert into function_table values (?,?)', row)
for row in var_func:
    c.execute ('insert into var_func_table values (?,?,?)', row)

# Save (commit) the change
conn.commit
conn.close
```

Comment: Have you tried to delete/rename `python_database` file and run the code again?

Comment: Would you mind posting the full traceback?

Comment: OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-7afdcbb88c10> in <module>()
     48     moudule text,
     49     type text,
---> 50     desc text)''')
     51 
     52 c.execute('''CREATE table function_table(

OperationalError: table variable_table already exists